# How do I upload file to Azure function while publishing the code from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I have created a `Azure Function`, which is having a dependency on `ini` file.

```
 public class DataProcessingFunction
 {
    FunctionName("DataProcessingFunction")]
    public async Task Run([EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent,ILogger log)
    {
        string iniFolderPath = $@"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\Ini\";
        string iniFileName = "Sample.ini";
        var iniConfig = FileManager.ReadFile(iniFolderPath, iniFileName);
    }
 }
```

I have selected `Copy if never` option in Visual Studio while publishing the code to Azure function
Also, I have tried selecting `Embedded Resource`. But I am not able to find the file

[image]

I get an exception

> File not found.

Add/Upload option in Azure portal is disabled because I am publishing the function from Visual studio

Question: Do I need to upload file to blob and then refer it in a code?

Comment: Function is deployed to azure, it is actually deployed to kudu, you modify Sample.ini to Copy if newer, then in theory it should be able to successfully transfer to kudu's d drive. Check if you have this file in kudu. I think it should have uploaded successfully.

Comment: I think it should upload successfully. Is there Sample.ini under D:\home\site\wwwroot> in your kudu? Please check.

Comment: yes, you are right, I can see it under wwwroot. So what path I should use it in code?

Comment: What is the internal logic of FileManager.ReadFile, or which package is this method in ? Is this a method wrote by yourself?

Comment: Yes, internally it uses StreamReader to read the file by passing file path.

Comment: The problem comes from `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, which is not reliable in Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the way to do it.**

`ExecutionContext context;` // You can modify your function method to take an additional parameter of type ExecutionContext

`public static async Task Run(<.... Other parameters>, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)`

Then build the path by combining function directory, "templates" is the directory I have in the function app project which is deployed along with other code, emails.html is file within templates (For each of these files you have to set, copy-always or copy-if-newer in the properties.). Instead of templates you can have your .ini file.

`string templatePath = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "Templates", "emails.html");`

Answer (score 2):

The final conclusion is that the file was successfully uploaded, the problem is that an error occurred while reading the path. It seems that using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` in Azure is not reliable.

I just tried it and `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` got the wrong path in azure (I printed it out and it showed `"D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\2.0.12961\32bit"`, This is obviously not the current folder), and eventually it fails to find the Sample.ini file. Since the function is your own, you can set the path to something like `"D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot>\\Ini\\Sample.ini"`. This should read the Sample.ini file.

Comment: what is the guarantee it will always have D drive? Is there any way to get wwwroot folder path using built in functions?

Comment: @kudlatiger The so-called "deploy to Azure" is actually uploading the compiled file to the `D:\home\site\wwwroot` folder of kudu (Azure Function belongs to the web app sandbox, the principle is the same). When you use Azure Web app , `D:\home\site\wwwroot` is always your physical root path.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use, `context.FunctionAppDirectory`. We must use `..` prefix in front of the file name we are specifying. So that it goes in the folder:

```
C:\home\site\wwwroot
```

Which should be programmatically as follows, in `C#`

```
Path.Combine(executionContext.FunctionDirectory, @"..\\test.txt");
```

Or if we don't care too much about the path we can use:-

```
Path.Combine(Path.getTempPath(), "test.txt");
```