# Unable to Add a file in Azure function

Tags: azure-functions

I have created and published an azure function . My solution has one file called abc.json which is being added with function project in Visual studio. I am able to successfully debug my code but when publishing and after deployment , i get error in log file as could not find file abc.json? what wrong am I doing? and how can I fix this?
I have right clicked on abc.json and selected "Content" and "Copy Always"

My code:

```
 public static class MyFunctionClass
    {
        private static readonly string _endpointUrl = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "endpointUrl" );
        private static readonly string _primaryKey = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "primaryKey" );
        private static readonly string source_databaseId = "mydb";        
        private static readonly string target_containerId = "mycollection";
        public static Dictionary<string, string> projectCustomerNameMapping =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>( File.ReadAllText( "abc.json" ) );




        [FunctionName( "CopyActivity" )]
        public static async Task Run( [CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "mydb",
            collectionName: "mycollection",
            StartFromBeginning = true,
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true,
            LeaseCollectionPrefix= "testprefix"

    )] IReadOnlyList<Document> source,
    ILogger log )
        {.... my logics..}
```

Comment: Is this file being copied to published folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the function method and add the additional parameter `ExecutionContext context`
like below code.

`public static async Task Run(<.... Other parameters>, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)`

You can build the path by combining the function directory, and also check the file path and set something like below
`"D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot>\\Ini\\Sample.ini"`

Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60319034) for related discussions.